# I'm using reportlab to generate PDF in python. When a table extends to multiple pages, how to draw a line below the last row on each page?

Tags: reportlab

I'm using `reportlab` to generate PDF in python. When a table extends to multiple pages, how to draw a line below the last row on each page?

Setting the `linebelow` in `tablestyle` on generate the line below the last row of the whole table, but since the table is split into multiple pages, I would like to have a line below the last row of each page.

By setting `repeatRow=1` can repeat head row on each page, I was expecting some thing similar and straightforward to achieve my purpose.